# Make small sets of files using xargs to process using imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, xargs

I have about 230 images in a folder and want to make pdf files in set of 20 images so I did this as imagemagick can't process more than 22 picture as distribute pixel chach gets exhausted on my system
Here lim is number of files to be made
f is number of flies in one batch
arrPics is an arrey of the image files
v is the variable to store the number passed from the first xargs

```
seq $lim | xargs -I{} -nfind${arrPics[@]} |xargs -I{} -i -t -n "$f" convert -limit memory 1GiB -limit disk 1gb -verbose {} -quality 100 "$v.pdf"
```

I tried

```
find ${arrPics[@]} | xargs -I{} -i -t -n "$f"  convert - limit memory 1GiB -limit disk 1gb -verbose {} -quality 100 "(($count++)).pdf
```

earlier but count is not getting incremented is it that xargs can't increment a variable or am I doing it wrong.
One more question is that is multiple xargs approach wrong ?as it basically like piping the output of one command to another pipe and then dumping it together.

Comment: Why do you think you are using a distributed pixel cache, when you are not? Why are you limiting memory and disk - how will that help? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If you are writing one image to pdf at a time, you could use mogrify to process all images in a folder. If you are trying to write 20 images at a time as one 20-page pdf, then you could simply write a pair of nested loops to process 20 images at a time using convert. How big are each input image?

Comment: each image is about 1.5 Mb in size and nested loops need to be thought about